# How to call a return value from a function into another function that has already a parameter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have $result which contains my query to perform this task, it works fine and I dont have any problem with it but I want to use the return value of the first function (buildRatingSystem) in my second function in order to perform the task, could anyone help me how to do it cause I have tried bucket of things but nothing is working. I was thinking of making $average as a global variable but nothing worked so please need help. Thanks ahead

```
function buildRatingSystem( array $result): string
{
$ratingNumber = 0;
$count = 0;
// Initialize Global variables in order to be used in other parts of the website
$GLOBALS['fiveStarRating'] = 0;
$GLOBALS['fourStarRating'] = 0;
$GLOBALS['threeStarRating'] = 0;
$GLOBALS['twoStarRating'] = 0;
$GLOBALS['oneStarRating'] = 0;

foreach($result as $rate) {
$ratingNumber+= $rate['ratingNumber'];
$count += 1;
if($rate['ratingNumber'] == 5) {
$GLOBALS['fiveStarRating'] +=1;
}
else if($rate['ratingNumber'] == 4) {
$GLOBALS['fourStarRating'] +=1;
}
else if($rate['ratingNumber'] == 3) {
$GLOBALS['threeStarRating'] +=1;
}
else if($rate['ratingNumber'] == 2) {
$GLOBALS['twoStarRating'] +=1;
}
else if($rate['ratingNumber'] == 1) {
$GLOBALS['oneStarRating'] +=1;
}
;
}
return $average= $ratingNumber/$count ;
}
```

This is the second function where i want to use value in $average

```
function buildProductsDisplay(array $products): string
{
foreach ($products as $product) {
$html .= '<div >’;
$averageRating = round($average, 0);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
$ratingClassStar = "fa-star-o";
if($i <= $averageRating) {
$ratingClassStar = "fa-star";
}
$html .="<i class='fa $ratingClassStar'></i>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
}
return $html;
}
```

Comment: Pass it as a parameter? You clearly know how to do that since both of your functions take parameters.

Comment: Aside from that, you have a syntax issue here: `$html .= '<div >’;`, you close it off with a fancy quote. Is this in actual code or only an error in the question?

Comment: @El_Vanja, please, my second function has a parameter already passed but i find this one difficult to, ca you help or show me

Comment: It doesn't matter that it already has a parameter. The number of parameters is not limited to one. Just pass it as a second one. See example #2 in the [manual about function arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Comment: Here the error thrown after I pass 2 parameters "Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function buildProductsDisplay(), 1 passed in"

Comment: That means you are not actually passing the parameter in the place where you call the function. You have probably only added the second parameter in the function definition.

Comment: Please show the piece of code you wrote yet about the way you call the functions and full error messages about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and answer your question. See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example